# sqlalchemy mapping multiple entries to the same backref

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Perhaps this is a design issue but I have a case where I have a class that defines a default part, and alternate_parts.

```
 class Entity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "entity"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    part_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('part.id'))
    part = relationship("Part", backref="entities")
    alternate_parts = relationship("Part", secondary="associate_entity_to_parts", backref="entities")

    ...

 class Part(Base):
    __tablename__ = "part"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)      

    ...
```

This throws an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'entities' on relationship 'Entity.alternate_parts': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Parts|part'
```

The purpose of this is that I want to be able to reverse look up any entities that refer to this part including ones where they are alternates. The reason for storing the alternates in this way is that this way I don't have to to store some kind of a "default" part id somewhere.

Any suggestions?